# How do I get actual class of JXA object

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

I’m trying to differentiate between iTunes playlists that are folders and ones that aren’t.

In AppleScript there seem to be two ways to do this:

1. I can get all folder playlists and process them individually from user playlists:

   ```
   set userPlaylists to user playlists
   set folderPlaylists to folder playlists
   -- …do processing
   ```
2. I can check the class of a playlist using `class of pl is folder playlist` (where `pl` is my playlist).

Both methods don’t seem to work with JXA.

The first method does not work because accessing `.folderPlaylists()` results in `Error: Message not understood` (where `app = Application('iTunes')`). Every other type of playlist can be accessed this way (`app.playlists()`, `app.libraryPlaylists()`, `app.radioTunerPlaylists()`, `app.subscriptionPlaylists()`, `app.userPlaylists()`, `app.audioCDPlaylists()` all work). Is this a bug?

So I tried replicating the second method. As far as I understood, `ObjectSpecifier.classOf` should give me the object type as a string. However, it only returns the type that was requested by the object specifier that gave me the object.

So while in AppleScript `class of (first item of (playlists whose name is "«Name of a folder playlist»"))` gives me `folder playlist`, `ObjectSpecifier.classOf(app.playlists.whose({name: '«Name of a folder playlist»'})()[0])` just returns `"playlist"` (presumably because I used `app.playlists` to get to the object).

Isn’t there a function that would return the actual type of the playlist (e.g. `"folder playlist"`, or `"user playlist"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get folders from the playlists:

```
folderList = itunesApp.playlists.whose({_match: [ObjectSpecifier().class, 'folderPlaylist']})()
```

---

To differentiate between userPlaylist and folderPlaylist from a playlist object:

- use: `myobj.class() == 'folderPlaylist'`

> ```
> myList = itunesApp.playlists()
> for (var i in myList) {
>     if (myList[i].class() == 'folderPlaylist') { 
>
>     } else if (myList[i].class() == 'userPlaylist') {
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: So simple, yet so elusive… Thanks a lot!